# Permissions using php class and if statements

Tags: php, html, if-statement, permissions

I currently have a permission's function in one of my php classes, then in my database I declare the permissions for each user group.

In my site code of html I include an if statement like below to only show for certain user permissions.

The only issue I have is,  an example would be the instructor permission can access everything a standard user can and anything specific to an instructor.

This works fine, however as I also include a manager permission that can access everything everyone else can plus more.

I get no errors for people with no permissions and no errors for managers that have access to everything.

However when I log in as an instructor I get undefined variable of 'manager' because that group doesn't have access to the manager fields but I just want it to ignore it if it doesn't have permission to see that part not display undefined variable. print screens of my class, DB set up and code below.

An example of only showing the html code on screen when user has manager permission, same for instructor just with instructor written in the if statement.

```
<?php if($user->hasPermission('manager')) { ?>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"    aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span>   Manager Reports</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="#">Financial Reports</a> </li>
<li><a href="#">Employee Report</a> </li>
<li><a href="#">Lesson Report</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  <?php } ?>
```

My hasPermissions functions in my php class

```
public function hasPermission($key){
    $group = $this->_db->get('groups', array('ID', '=', $this->data()->group));

    if($group->count()) {
        $permissions = json_decode($group->first()->permissions, true);

        if($permissions[$key] == true) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

[Set up in DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CtWc.png)

[Error I get when logged in as instructor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFqmH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your permissions check:

```
if (array_key_exists($key, $permissions) && $permissions[$key] == true)) {
    return true;
}
```

This checks that the given `$key` is in the `$permissions` array and if not, skips checking the value.

Comment: Works perfectly, being trying to figure that out for ages! much appreciated! thank you.